# Which client authentication methods make sense when calling `initdb`?

Tags: postgresql, authentication

Postgres offers many [client authentication methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html):

- Trust Authentication
- Password Authentication
- GSSAPI Authentication
- SSPI Authentication
- Ident Authentication
- Peer Authentication
- LDAP Authentication
- RADIUS Authentication
- Certificate Authentication
- PAM Authentication
- BSD Authentication

The client authentication method flags on [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html):

- `-A` or `--auth`
- `--auth-host`
- `--auth-local`

…specify the default authentication method for users used in `pg_hba.conf`.

I am making a [Wizard tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software)) for creating an [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html) string, the string to be executed by someone setting up a new Postgres cluster. This led me to contemplate all the possible values for authentication with `initdb`.

➥ Of the list above, which are practical/sensible for use with `initdb`?

Obviously [`trust`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html) is the simplest way to get started, though usually best to change soon after the cluster is established.

Some are not practical. For example, [PAM authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pam.html) requires that the user must already exist in the database. So PAM cannot be used for setting up a new cluster with `initdb`.

I am not familiar with several of the other authentication methods. And I am no security expect. This leaves me wondering: Which of the client authentication methods could be used practically/sensibly with `initdb`?

Comment: I think more its more practical to generate a on the fly `pg_hba.conf` file and override existing one according to users' choice. I would vote for; `--auth-host=md5`(or `scram-sha-256` after version 11) and `--auth-local=peer` (not available for some platforms)

Comment: all of them are sensible depending on the context.

Comment: @Jasen No, they are not all practical/sensible. As I pointed out in the Question, PAM cannot be used because of a Catch-22 where the database must have a user already in the database but you can’t establish that user because you don’t have a way to authenticate a user connection to establish that user.

Comment: anything is possible in single user mode.

Comment: Also usually there's a "local peer" entry in pg_hba for the process owner with superuser permissions  this is needed by internals like autovacuum.

Comment: You found a way to specify the default `postgres` user's password prior to running the `initdb` command ? I tried setting the `export PGPASSWORD=$DB_ROOT_PASSWORD` environment variable but it didn't help.

Comment: You can change that at any time later in `pg_hba.conf` so which one you use during initdb doesn't really matter.